# How to import UniswapV2Router02 interface into a smart contract on Truffle?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I am creating a sample Uniswap project and was able to import the Uniswap github interface as

```
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
```

on Remix.
However, in my local React-Js project (compiling with Truffle), this doesnt work.
I tried installing the uniswap packages and doing

```
import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
```

but I get this following error:

```
 ParserError: Source "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol" not found
import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
```

Comment: What is your Truffle version? Did you verify the path is correct?

Comment: Solved it - I had imported the uniswap package in tbe wrong directory (client instead of root) so truffle wasn't able to recognize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it - I had imported the uniswap package in tbe wrong directory (client instead of root) so truffle wasn't able to recognize